# How to create a sequence with leading zeroes using brace expansion

Tags: bash, arithmetic, brace-expansion

When I use the following, I get a result as expected:

```
$ echo {8..10}
8 9 10
```

How can I use this brace expansion in an easy way, to get the following output?

```
$ echo {8..10}
08 09 10
```

I now that this may be obtained using `seq` (didn't try), but that is not what I am looking for.

Useful info may be that I am restricted to this bash version. (If you have a `zsh` solution, but no `bash` solution, please share as well)

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu)
```

Comment: Some hint to do this in bash 3 I found here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/018 However, the approach outlined there is not convenient.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789729/zero-padding-in-bash

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Prefix the first number with a `0` to force each term to have the same  width.

```
$ echo {08..10}
08 09 10
```

From the bash man page section on Brace Expansion:

> Supplied integers may be prefixed with 0 to force each term to have
>   the same  width.  When  either  x or y begins with a zero, the shell
>   attempts to force all generated terms to contain the same number of
>   digits, zero-padding where necessary.

Also note that you can use `seq` with the `-w` option to equalize width by padding with leading zeroes:

```
$ seq -w 8 10
08
09
10

$ seq -s " " -w 8 10
08 09 10
```

If you want more control, you can even specify a printf style format:

```
$ seq -s " " -f %02g 8 10
08 09 10
```

Comment: After just found out about the `echo {08..10}` solution, however, it is only introduced for bash version 4 and up.

Comment: That makes me a little uncomfortable that bash does that.  For a bunch of utilities (for example `perl`) a leading zero indicates an octal number.  I suppose it is not often you want a sequence of octal numbers...

Comment: It should be noted that you can also prefix the numbers when giving then to `seq` with the `-w` switch like so: `seq -w 003` produces the numbers 001, 002, and 003.

Comment: @kurtm don't worry about leading zeroes. That could hurt when something tries to parse a number. What this is really useful at is to generate a file name sequence `foo_00001.someextension` where nearly all sorting contexts provide a sane ordering.

Comment: The echo {08..10} option is not working on centos bash

Answer (score 13):

I have the same bash version of the original poster (`GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release`) and `{08..12}` doesn't work for me, but the following does:

```
for i in 0{8..9} {10..12}; do echo $i; done
08
09
10
11
12
```

It's a little more tedious, but it does work on the OP version of bash (and later versions, I would assume).

Comment: I did not think about this solution (although in my case I actually also want to number 0001 1000, but your principle works of course.

Answer (score 10):

if you use printf

```
printf "%.2d " {8..10}
```

this will force to be 2 chars and will add a leading 0. In case  you need 3 digits you can change to "%.3d ".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the `printf` solution, but it is not really making this easier. I am hoping that there is some hidden trick that does the job :)

Comment: This is the only answer that seems versatile enough to handle any circumstance for origin of the number to pad. I'm using a counter as I loop through files. This printf solution zero pads flawlessly while all others seem to focus on generating zero-padded numbers rather than zero-padding existing numbers.

Answer (score 9):

Use a range that starts with a constant digit and strip that digit off:

```
echo \ {108..110} | sed 's/ 1//g'
```

or without using an external command:

```
a=({108..110}); echo "${a[@]#1}"
```

For use in a for loop:

```
for x in {108..110}; do
  x=${x#1}
  …
done
```

though for this case a while loop would be clearer and works in any POSIX shell:

```
x=8
while [ $x -le 10 ]; do
  n=$((100+x)); n=${n#1}
  …
  x=$((x+1))
done
```

Comment: I accepted this answer above the other answers, because it satisfies the request for Bash 3.x. Especially as I needed the `for` loop anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, I think automatic fixed-width only occurs with the latest version of bash:

```
$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

$ echo test{00..05}
test0 test1 test2 test3 test4 test5
```

Answer (score -3):

```
for i in $(seq -s " " -f %0${zeros}g $ini $fin); do ....;done
```

`zeros`, `ini` and `fin` are variables, so its easy to fit to your needs. It  pads the digits to $zeros zeros from $ini to $fin without problems ;)