# Creating a range of numbers from 08 to 10 in bash doesn't include 0 in front of one digit numbers

Tags: linux, bash, brace-expansion

On my local machine, where I run CentOS 7.2, when I do this:

```
for i in {8..12}; do echo ${i}; done
```

I got:

```
8
9
10
```

But when I do this:

```
for i in {08..10}; do echo ${i}; done
```

I got:

```
08
09
10
```

But on server to which I have access, which runs CentOS 5.6, running both commands results in the same output:

```
8
9
10
```

Why there are no zeroes in front of 8 and 9? Is it because of bash version, or just environment configuration? Can I change it per session or permanently, so my server will put that zero in front of numbers smaller than 10?

Comment: Brace expansion with zero-filling was introduced in Bash 4.  Your CentOS installation may use Bash 3?

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60257/how-to-create-a-sequence-with-leading-zeroes-using-brace-expansion

Comment: may be use `printf '%02d\n' {8..12}`

Comment: @Kusalananda: yes, you were right. I didn't noticed your answer before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probable that the `bash` on your CentOS 5.6 machine is version 3.  Zero-filling of integers in brace expansions was introduced in version 4 of `bash`.

The solution would be to either update your installation of `bash` to a more recent version, or to use an alternative way of generating the zero-filled integers, like

```
printf '%02d\n' {8..10}
```

Alternatively, something along the lines of

```
for i in 0{1..9} {10..20}; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

will also work.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Bash on my CentOS 7.2 is 4.x version, and bash on that server which I mentioned is 3.x version. I am marking this as a solution since I mostly wanted to learn why is the difference happening. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `bash`, you could use `zsh` where that syntax comes from.

`zsh` has been supporting `{08..10}` since 1995 (introduced in 2.6-beta4), so will be available in the `zsh` of any version of CentOS (first release of CentOS in 2004).

You did actually use `zsh` syntax in your example as in `bash` you need `echo "${i}"` instead of `echo ${i}` for the expansion of `$i` not to be subject to word splitting (and so dependant on `$IFS`).

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I wasn't aware that it comes from zsh.

Comment: @Learner, most `bash` features come from `ksh`, a few from `csh`/`tcsh` like history expansion, and a few from `zsh`. It has very few of its own.

Answer (score 1):

alternative, you can use `seq` command

```
$ seq -f "%02g" 8 10
08
09
10
```